# Spring Security 3.0.3.RELEASE

Tags: grails

I got the following warning, when i imported a project in GGTS 3.1.0 release, could anyone suggest me a solution for this warning.

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.core;3.0.3.RELEASE

```
==== grailsPlugins: tried

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.core;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.core.jar:

  C:\GrailsWs\hubbub/lib/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

  C:\Users\ard004\.grails\2.1.1\projects\hubbub\plugins\hibernate-2.1.1/lib/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

  C:\Users\ard004\.grails\2.1.1\projects\hubbub\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3/lib/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

  C:\Users\ard004\.grails\2.1.1\projects\hubbub\plugins\tomcat-2.1.1/lib/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

  C:\Users\ard004\.grails\2.1.1\projects\hubbub\plugins\webxml-1.4.1/lib/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== grailsHome: tried

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.springframework.security/org.springframework.security.core/ivy-3.0.3.RELEASE.xml

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.core;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.core.jar:

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.springframework.security/org.springframework.security.core/jars/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.springframework.security/org.springframework.security.core/bundles/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== grailsHome: tried

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.xml

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.core;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.core.jar:

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== grailsHome: tried

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1\dist/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.xml

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.core;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.core.jar:

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1\dist/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== grailsHome: tried

  C:\Users\ard004\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.xml

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.core;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.core.jar:

  C:\Users\ard004\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== grailsHome: tried

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.core;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.core.jar:

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1/plugins/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== grailsCentral: tried

  http://grails.org/plugins/grails-org.springframework.security.core/tags/RELEASE_3.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.pom

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.core;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.core.jar:

  http://grails.org/plugins/grails-org.springframework.security.core/tags/RELEASE_3.0.3.RELEASE/grails-org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried

  http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/springframework/security/org.springframework.security.core/3.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.pom

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.core;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.core.jar:

  http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/springframework/security/org.springframework.security.core/3.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== mavenCentral: tried

  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/org.springframework.security.core/3.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.pom

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.core;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.core.jar:

  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/org.springframework.security.core/3.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

    module not found: org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.web;3.0.3.RELEASE

==== grailsPlugins: tried

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.web;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.web.jar:

  C:\GrailsWs\hubbub/lib/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

  C:\Users\ard004\.grails\2.1.1\projects\hubbub\plugins\hibernate-2.1.1/lib/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

  C:\Users\ard004\.grails\2.1.1\projects\hubbub\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3/lib/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

  C:\Users\ard004\.grails\2.1.1\projects\hubbub\plugins\tomcat-2.1.1/lib/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

  C:\Users\ard004\.grails\2.1.1\projects\hubbub\plugins\webxml-1.4.1/lib/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== grailsHome: tried

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.springframework.security/org.springframework.security.web/ivy-3.0.3.RELEASE.xml

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.web;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.web.jar:

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.springframework.security/org.springframework.security.web/jars/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.springframework.security/org.springframework.security.web/bundles/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== grailsHome: tried

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.xml

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.web;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.web.jar:

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== grailsHome: tried

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1\dist/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.xml

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.web;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.web.jar:

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1\dist/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== grailsHome: tried

  C:\Users\ard004\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.xml

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.web;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.web.jar:

  C:\Users\ard004\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== grailsHome: tried

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.web;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.web.jar:

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1/plugins/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== grailsCentral: tried

  http://grails.org/plugins/grails-org.springframework.security.web/tags/RELEASE_3.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.pom

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.web;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.web.jar:

  http://grails.org/plugins/grails-org.springframework.security.web/tags/RELEASE_3.0.3.RELEASE/grails-org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried

  http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/springframework/security/org.springframework.security.web/3.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.pom

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.web;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.web.jar:

  http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/springframework/security/org.springframework.security.web/3.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== mavenCentral: tried

  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/org.springframework.security.web/3.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.pom

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.web;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.web.jar:

  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/org.springframework.security.web/3.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :: org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.core;3.0.3.RELEASE: not found

    :: org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.web;3.0.3.RELEASE: not found

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.core;3.0.3.RELEASE

```
==== grailsPlugins: tried

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.core;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.core.jar:

  C:\GrailsWs\hubbub/lib/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

  C:\Users\ard004\.grails\2.1.1\projects\hubbub\plugins\hibernate-2.1.1/lib/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

  C:\Users\ard004\.grails\2.1.1\projects\hubbub\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3/lib/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

  C:\Users\ard004\.grails\2.1.1\projects\hubbub\plugins\tomcat-2.1.1/lib/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

  C:\Users\ard004\.grails\2.1.1\projects\hubbub\plugins\webxml-1.4.1/lib/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== grailsHome: tried

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.springframework.security/org.springframework.security.core/ivy-3.0.3.RELEASE.xml

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.core;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.core.jar:

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.springframework.security/org.springframework.security.core/jars/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.springframework.security/org.springframework.security.core/bundles/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== grailsHome: tried

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.xml

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.core;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.core.jar:

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== grailsHome: tried

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1\dist/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.xml

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.core;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.core.jar:

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1\dist/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== grailsHome: tried

  C:\Users\ard004\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.xml

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.core;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.core.jar:

  C:\Users\ard004\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== grailsHome: tried

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.core;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.core.jar:

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1/plugins/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== grailsCentral: tried

  http://grails.org/plugins/grails-org.springframework.security.core/tags/RELEASE_3.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.pom

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.core;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.core.jar:

  http://grails.org/plugins/grails-org.springframework.security.core/tags/RELEASE_3.0.3.RELEASE/grails-org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried

  http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/springframework/security/org.springframework.security.core/3.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.pom

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.core;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.core.jar:

  http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/springframework/security/org.springframework.security.core/3.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== mavenCentral: tried

  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/org.springframework.security.core/3.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.pom

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.core;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.core.jar:

  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/org.springframework.security.core/3.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

    module not found: org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.web;3.0.3.RELEASE

==== grailsPlugins: tried

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.web;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.web.jar:

  C:\GrailsWs\hubbub/lib/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

  C:\Users\ard004\.grails\2.1.1\projects\hubbub\plugins\hibernate-2.1.1/lib/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

  C:\Users\ard004\.grails\2.1.1\projects\hubbub\plugins\spring-security-core-1.2.7.3/lib/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

  C:\Users\ard004\.grails\2.1.1\projects\hubbub\plugins\tomcat-2.1.1/lib/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

  C:\Users\ard004\.grails\2.1.1\projects\hubbub\plugins\webxml-1.4.1/lib/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== grailsHome: tried

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.springframework.security/org.springframework.security.web/ivy-3.0.3.RELEASE.xml

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.web;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.web.jar:

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.springframework.security/org.springframework.security.web/jars/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.springframework.security/org.springframework.security.web/bundles/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== grailsHome: tried

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.xml

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.web;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.web.jar:

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== grailsHome: tried

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1\dist/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.xml

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.web;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.web.jar:

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1\dist/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== grailsHome: tried

  C:\Users\ard004\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.xml

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.web;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.web.jar:

  C:\Users\ard004\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== grailsHome: tried

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.web;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.web.jar:

  C:\Softwares\groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32\springsource\grails-2.1.1/plugins/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== grailsCentral: tried

  http://grails.org/plugins/grails-org.springframework.security.web/tags/RELEASE_3.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.pom

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.web;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.web.jar:

  http://grails.org/plugins/grails-org.springframework.security.web/tags/RELEASE_3.0.3.RELEASE/grails-org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core: tried

  http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/springframework/security/org.springframework.security.web/3.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.pom

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.web;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.web.jar:

  http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/springframework/security/org.springframework.security.web/3.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

==== mavenCentral: tried

  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/org.springframework.security.web/3.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.pom

  -- artifact org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.web;3.0.3.RELEASE!org.springframework.security.web.jar:

  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/org.springframework.security.web/3.0.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.security.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :: org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.core;3.0.3.RELEASE: not found

    :: org.springframework.security#org.springframework.security.web;3.0.3.RELEASE: not found

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.springframework.security:org.springframework.security.core:3.0.3.RELEASE
- org.springframework.security:org.springframework.security.web:3.0.3.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

There are two different sets of Spring-related JAR files in public Maven repositories.  The ones in Maven Central use artifact IDs of the form `spring-*`, the ones in the SpringSource [EBR](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/) use artifact IDs of the form `org.springframework.*`.  Old versions (before 1.2) of the Grails spring-security-core plugin used to depend on the EBR artifacts, which in turn requires you to enable the EBR Maven repository in your BuildConfig.  More recent versions (1.2 and later) use the Maven Central artifacts instead.

Comment: Thanks Ian, it has worked by installing all plugins whatever provided in application.properties and by using maven central